# How to offer a Kerberos Negotiate Authentication HTTP Server-Side with Perl

Tags: perl, http, webserver, kerberos

I'm trying to write a Perl-based web application, that uses Kerberos 5 Negotiate Authentication to authenticate its users. The Perl web framework I'm using is Perl Dancer, in its non-CGI, self-contained operating mode. I'm running this on the Fedora distro of Linux.

Negotiate Authentication can use existing Kerberos tickets forwarded from the users' browsers, or use regular Basic Authentication to allow the users to establish their first Kerberos tickets. The end effect of this is the sites that support Negotiate Authentication are seamlessly integrated into the SSO environment.

CPAN has the Authen::Krb5 module, which I suspect would be the foundation of offering Negotiate Authentication, however I can only find client-side modules on CPAN. These client-side modules can be used as a back-end for really simple Basic Authentication, or for establishing the first Negotiate Authentication ticket, but cannot perform Negotiate Authentication itself (ex. Authen::Krb5::Easy).

I have found an implementation for PHP [here](http://mbechler.eenterphace.org/blog/index.php?/archives/5-php_krb5-beta-Negotiate-auth-with-GSSAPI-for-PHP.html). The accompanying [how to guide](http://mbechler.eenterphace.org/blog/index.php?/archives/6-Doing-GSSNegotiate-SSO-using-Mozilla-Firefox,-MIT-Kerberos-and-PHP.html) gives a good high-level idea of how Negotiate Authentication should work, and how a Negotiate Authentication library written for Perl (or any language) might be used in a web application. Ideally I would like to use a Perl library with a similar interface to this PHP one.

Does a Perl Negotiate Authentication server-side library exist? 
What would be the best way to write one if none exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more searching, and basically all libraries implementing the server side of Negotiate/SPENGO/RFC4559 are written in C, and usually based upon Apache's mod_auth_kerb.

Though no Perl libraries surfaced, I did find one for Python 2, called [PyKerberos](http://trac.calendarserver.org/browser/PyKerberos/trunk). It appears to be well explained in the source (something severely lacking from other libraries), and, as a bonus, it seems this Python 2 module is widely available from distro package repositories (python-kerberos in Fedora).

Currently, it appears the best answer to my question is to call PyKerberos from Perl via Perl's Inline::Python module. This solution is probably slow (Perl -> Python -> C), but since my application doesn't have any serious performance requirements, it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You `mod_auth_kerb` or `mod_auth_spnego` and read `REMOTE_USER` from server env. You're done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the critical thing is that this application is not operating through CGI, and can't use Apache modules. I would very much prefer a standalone solution that doesn't involve Apache or similar HTTPDs.

If no non-CGI solutions present themselves, this may well be the route I take.

Comment: Well, I have no experience with the Perl modules. I could make a quick code review in order to see that it would work or not.